# Send display to user from a root job

Tags: python, linux, root

I have a job that starts in crontab with root privilege. This job should display a popup message after a while. The job is in python and use MessageBox toolkit.

With roit, the job works and after 5 minutes, I see the messagebox. 
The problem is that if I login as a user, I can see the job running in the tasks list but the popup does not work (probably since the display of the job is of the root and not the user).

I cant find the way to change this job to use the display of the current ligin user.

Is there a way to change this so the user will see the popup?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you try to set the DISPLAY variable ?

Comment: Have you tried achieving your task? what have you tried? can you post a [minimal, verifiable, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @bracco23. The python job that run in cron have a messagebox that popup after 5 minuts. When I log in as root it works. When I log in as user1, I can see that the job is running but the message box does not. So I am trying to achieve my task but dont know how.

Comment: I edited the post to add more info @piarston

Comment: Can you post the relevant code of what you have tried? a [mcve] is helpful.

Comment: Can you show the ouput of `crontab -l` for root?

Answer (score 2):

The MessageBox does not popup because the cron job run in an environment where the DISPLAY (environment variable) is not set. Instead of having cron run your python directly, you can make it run a simple wrapper around it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export DISPLAY=':0'
python /path/to/your/python/program.sh
```

Alternatively, if your confident it won't mess with other cron jobs, you can add `DISPLAY=:0` as the first line of your crontab.